# Execute a method in java to check the time and execute a method on certain times

Tags: java

I'm running an IRC bot and it needs to echo a message in the chat between two set hours and do this every few minutes :

I tried to do :

```
        public void timerTest(int minH,int maxH, int minT){
        boolean b = true;
        boolean timeout = false;
        while(b){
            while(!timeout){
                if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= minH && c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= maxH && c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % minT == 0){   
                    sendMessage(channel,spam1.getMessage());
                    timeout = true;
                  }
                }
                if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%minT == 1){
                    timeout = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

I normally want to spam a message every 15 minutes between 2 and 6. I tried putting it in an unendless while loop, but this is not recommended. I looked for Timer and TimerTask but I can't figure out how to properly do it. If someone would be so kind to explain how I can achieve this ?

thank you ^^

Comment: and none of "related questions" on the right of your post helped you?

Comment: Why is a loop not recommended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Execute a method at a specified time interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972845/java-execute-a-method-at-a-specified-time-interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Timer` and `TimerTask` are not really fitted for complex scheduling needs such as yours.

I would recommend looking into [`quartz`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It allows you to schedule e.g., using `cron` expressions which is quite powerful. I think something like the following expression could be useful:

```
*/15 2-6 * * * ?
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems incredible powerful, going to play around with it for a while :p

Comment: I still have a question though, I'm running my IRCbot but it still needs to be able to run a method in a class periodically because it uses another method from another object that can only be initialised one time. But I only seem able to schedule a class ?

Comment: @Lucas, you implement the `job` interface which lets you run a method. See [`Example 1 - Your First Quartz Program`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/Example1.html)

Answer (score 0):

a very simple idea might be to use Spring and the Task framework for doing this task
Have a look at
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

You could simply annotate your Class method with
`@Scheduled(cron = "*/15 2-6 * * * ?")`

Or if you don't want to include the spring dependencies, you could create an instance of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

```
    // set the poolsize to 1
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call method
        }
    }, 2,2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

This gives you the flexibility of scheduling a runnable which could just call your method periodically. Make sure you shutdown the executor on application shutdown, otherwise your app might hang.